# Progressive Rock song, c.2002, "girl with brown hair" "standing there in my dream"

Tags: identify-this-song

I heard this song on 99.7 KY in 2001 or 2002, when I was stationed at Fort Leavenworth, Kansas. It was on a Sunday. I contacted the station and have a list of all the songs played from 2002-2003, but this song may have been played as part of a syndicated program and not listed. So far, no research has indicated the title or artist. I wrote the title down back then.....but that car, that notepad...well its long gone!

This was a long time ago, and ive been trying to find this song ever since, talk about an earworm! 
I've searched several different search engines and methods over the last decade, but still...no dice. So I must be missing something.

It seems to be a 1970s era Classic Rock / Progressive Rock Song.
It starts with what seems like a wind noise, or kind of a dreamy state sound effect.
The lyrics I can remember include:
"do you remember"
"you were standing there in my dream" and this could have taken place "last night"
something something about a "girl with brown hair" which may have been "blowing in the wind". 
I can recall something about the song being set in Fall, but I cant remember exactly of course.

Its not Brown Eyed Girl, Diamonds and Rust, Street of Dreams, Last Night by the Travelling Wilburys, With the Wind and the Rain in Your Hair, and others that pop up with those terms.

---

Joseem has been helpful by suggesting some more musical points of information to add to my question. Keep in mind this was long ago, and my memory focuses on the words.

- The singer was a male, with a voice reminiscent of Paul Rogers from Bad Company or Van Morrison.
- As far as instrumentation, all I can recall is a haunting tone, perhaps a guitar or piano.
- The tempo was slow and the music never built up to a crescendo, like a long ballad.
- The rhythm was even throughout, I got the sense of a mourning, lull, woeful song.The beginning of and end of the song was a "swooshing" sound like wind was blowing across a barren plain or a rocky coastline.

I say it was a 70s classic or prog rock song, because it was on a classic rock station and this is the feeling I get when I remember the tone of the song. I realize it is hard to quantify a feeling, this song did not have any aggressive qualities that stood out, so it was not a heavy metal-esque, nor psychadelic, blues-rock, or acid-rock.

Comment: Try either "Fields Of Gold" by Sting, or "Sound Of Silence" by Simon & Garfunkel.  Neither are really Prog, but I could see how they might be mistaken for that genre.

Comment: Maybe 'Your Ghost' by Kristin Hersh : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Ghost - http://www.metrolyrics.com/your-ghost-lyrics-kristin-hersh.html ?

Comment: While the melodies and general "haunting feel" of all these suggestions are close, they are not the song I heard long ago.

Comment: Did you ever find out the song? If not, any additional information you might remember?

Comment: @unhandledexceptsean unfortunately, still looking! I can't think of any more detail at this point.

Answer (score 2):

How about **Not A Dry Eye In The House** by **Meat Loaf**? It's not from the 70's but fits the bill of Classic Rock and (it seems to me) your description.

EDIT: As requested by Chris here's a few more details about my suggestion:

https://youtu.be/aKspGNCkSAc

- has wind sound in the beginning and ending
- classic rock genre
- piano based instrumentation
- long ballad
- male vocalist
- lyrics excerpts:

"I can still see you standing there"
"Midnight wind blowin' thorough your hair, remember"
"And the dream was over"

It seemed like a good fit...

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it is the song Moriah.  (This is not Moriah from Spooky Tooth nor is it They Call the Wind Maria from Paint Your Wagon). I am trying to remember what group it was, but it was definitely early 70's prog.  If I'm not mistaken, the album ended with a bagpipe version of Amazing Grace, which, back then, wasn't as common as now.

Comment: I tried to find this version of the song, but a recent pop singer has made looking for a song named "Moriah" difficult - the ones I found were not it, but very close in nature.

Comment: I agree, I've been trying to remember who did this for a while, too. I'm trying to remember all the groups I was listening to back then, trying to narrow it down, and I can remember everyone who it was not: T2, Budgie, PFM, Van der Graaf Generator, Captain Beyond, Hawkwind, Tangerine Dream, Be-Bop Deluxe, Camel, Gong, Soft Machine, Flash...

Comment: Still haven't found a song titles "Moriah" or "Maria" that matches. It has been fun trying!

Answer (score 1):

[*I'm Mandy Fly Me*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv8N6zSzL7k) by 10cc has a whooshing aeroplane and melancholy feel.

> I had a crazy dream
>   I told them me so
>   But they said no no no no

Comment: Thanks - downloaded it and listened, but it is not the one.The "feel" is right though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your "Remember" song? ["Schooldays"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HB8MqwfvpcQ), Gentle Giant, *3 Friends*.  I've been trying to pull this from my heart-mind; thought it was from Tales from Topographic Oceans.

It hit me!  GENTLE GIANT! Three Friends. Haunting, the soundtrack(s) of my teenage and young adult years. This song is haunting and heart-rending.

> September
>   When we were 
>   Together
>   Together
>   Together
>   Schooldays the happy days when we were going nowhere
>   Schooldays the happy time when we were feeling no care
>   Schooldays when three said that we'd better be friends forever

2:25 in, starts lead in to the heart-rending part. 3:56: "Remember. Remember when we..." "Wait for me"... and I break into tears.

Was lucky enough to see them live in the late 70's. Curious if this could be it.

Comment: That is a GREAT song, and made me thing about old friends too. Not the song i'm looking for though - but it has been a great addition to my collection.

Comment: This is an interesting song, but it doesn't seem to match any of the details from the question, except being a Prog Rock song from the 70s and having an unusual introduction.  In particular, this is uptempo, and the question specifies a ballad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not in Love by 10cc has vocal layering that sounds like white noise/wind. I always recall this song by the "wind sound" because it is so unique. The lyrics don't fit what you remember and provided, but that could be simply how your mind was trying to recall details. anyway, its worth a listen.

https://youtu.be/OtBHfxU2wmc

Answer (score 0):

Rhydian Roberts - sounds a lot like Meat Loaf. Horrible song though :s The lyrics fit perfectly. I'm thinking the song is right, but it's by someone else... not Meat Loaf and not R.Roberts... a different version. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wT7TzbCN4HE

Comment: Here's the original Meatloaf song. Wind sound effects too. I think this is it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKspGNCkSAc

Answer (score -1):

I'm just about 100% sure you're looking for Kayleigh by Marillion. Please let me know if this was it.

Comment: Hey, that's quite a good match indeed, I hope you got it!

Comment: At first glance - this seems really close...I'll definitely listen to the whole thing (and the rest of the album) It seems very possible that the sands of time have composited the lyrics of this song with others.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to fill it out with details, such as a link to the song and reasons why you think this is a match. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel Maryanovsky, the genre is close, and this is an awesome song - I had to check out Marillions catalog - but it is not the specific one I remember. Thank you for the input and the artist suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

it could be the song "The Boys Of Summer"

Was this the one?

Comment: could you add link to video of song?

Comment: ... yes, a link and maybe the name of the band, and some explanations on how it could fit.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps it is [*China Grove* by The Doobie Brothers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udSHItTjWyQ)?

Comment: could you add a video link ?

Comment: Nope, besides the other main points that don't match, that song is far too happy. Thanks though!